# Using the Win32 API without WinMain?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, win32gui

I'm trying to use the Win32 API from a DLL to handle it due to it's quite messy but I only know how to call it using WinMain. Is there I way I can call a method to invoke the window?

Comment: You need to provide more details on what you are trying to do. What dll, what call. Can you show some code on what you have tried and how it failed?

Comment: You have a lot to learn about programming Win32 API, my friend...

Comment: I don't have any code because of this problem. The reason why I'm asking this is because I want to know if I can simply call something from the Win32 API to create the window and handle it without getting into the WinMain mess. I want to be able to make a simple function like **Window window = new Window("Window Title", 640, 480)** in my DLL but I can't put the main method in my DLL.

Comment: What program is hosting your DLL?  Does it have an event loop?  And while you can't put `WinMain` in your DLL, you can put an event loop in.  In fact, the Windows DLLs already have an exported event loop, named `DialogBox`.

Comment: new Window(...) is not the Win32 API..!?

Comment: Win32 API uses WinMain, I don't want WinMain. I'm hoping someone can find a workaround though. The **new Window(...)** thing was what I'm aiming for in my DLL.

Comment: If all you need is some text on a window you could try `MessageBox`.

Comment: The question makes no sense. DLLs do not have a WinMain. You couldn't use it even if you wanted to.

Comment: @RaymondChenL the OP is saying that he only knows how to use the Win32 API from inside of `WinMain()`, not how to use it inside of a DLL.  That is what he is asking for help with.

Answer (score 2):

In your DLL you can declare point of enterance :

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
// use WINAPI
}
```